# How to add Virtual host web-site for apache2 service in Ubuntu

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I have never set up such setting in before but I need to add new Virtual host web-site for apache2 web-server in Ubuntu 12.04.

**I need to create a new conf file like /etc/apache2/sites-available/default for /var/www/sha-prc-corporate then use below command to enable the setting.

sudo a2ensite mynewsite
sudo service apache2 restart**

My question is if above method is correct? Also how to write it for the new conf file for /etc/apache2/sites-available/mynewsite?

Thanks for any advice.

Below pictures shows current setting for the web-server:
[image] --> This is default file

[image]--> All related files locates under /etc/apache2

[image]--> This is apache2.conf file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration seems to be correct, but it's difficult to parse a GIF file :)
Commands you showed are ok. If you create a `my_site.conf` in the `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and then you run `a2ensite my_site`, it automatically creates a `symbolic link` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`, in such a way enabling the VirtualHost.

Keep in mind that your `VirtualHost`, as I see, has no `ServerName`; it can cause conflict with the `default` one.

To match a specific URL, just add to your `VirtualHost` following directives:

```
ServerName myname.com
ServerAlias *.myname.com
```

Comment: Hi Echoes_86,

Thank you for your reply!
You are right. I also think it is strange for the default file.
I will have a try for your advice.

But could you help to explain more for ServerAlias? When should we use it?

Comment: The `ServerAlias` directive sets the alternate names for a host, for use with name-based virtual hosts. It means that when you make a request to your webserver, it catches the URL requested and compares it with the `ServerName` directive in VirtualHost. If no match is found, it tries using `ServerAlias` directive, that can add some alternate names. If a match is found, request is served.

Comment: Most common case:
`ServerName my-site.com`
`ServerAlias www.my-site.org`

Comment: You're welcome. If it's ok, Upvote/Accept my answer, so it's marked as resolution for the case.

Comment: OK, I just finished the accept. Pls check.